# Equal ranking with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array "player" that contains objects of players with a score :

```
player['toto'].point = 15;
player['titi'].point = 8;
player['tete'].point = 5;
player['tata'].point = 10;
player['tutu'].point = 15;
```

I want to know the top 3 best players, with possible ties. 
In our example, this is the result I expect:

```
best[1].player = "TOTO, TUTU";
best[1].point = 15;
best[2].player="TATA";
best[2].point = 10;
best[3].player="TITI";
best[2].point = 8;
```

Note that I try to display any ties. In the example, there are two players who are number 1 position: TOTO and TUTU.
I really do not have the level to do it in javascript I think. Someone to help me? Thanks.

Comment: Create an array from the object's properties, sort the array based on points (reversed), then iterate and group consecutively equal records.

Comment: @Jack: `player` seems to be a object, those can't be sorted.

Comment: Indeed it is an object, it must go I guess to sort it ...

Comment: @Cerbrus—Arrays are Objects. Objects with a suitable length property can have their numeric properties "sorted" just like an array can since [Array.prototype.sort](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11) is generic.

Comment: @RobG: Just try calling `sort` on `var obj = {'b':'b','a':'a'}`

Comment: I am assuming your new output is supposed to read `best[3].point = 8;` on the last line?

Comment: @Cerbrus–`Array.prototype.sort.call({0:1,1:0,length:2}) => {0:0,1:1,length:2}`. Just like an Array, the Object must have a suitable *length* property and only numeric property values are "sorted".

Comment: @RobG: So, a object can be sorted in edge cases where you might as well have used an array.
It doesn't even work when the keys aren't incremental (as in `0,1,3,7` as keys instead of `0,1,2,3`).
In the only case where that works, you are better off using a `array`, so you can just use `.sort` on it.

Comment: "Edge case"? It's written into the [language specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11). The keys don't need to be sequential: `[].sort.apply({5:5,1:1,8:8,0:0,length:4})` sorts just fine. Remember to set the length properly. My point is that plain Objects **can** be sorted in the same way Arrays are. Accessing the members using *for..in* can result in "out of order" enumeration, an incrementing or decrementing loop (*for*, *do*, *while*) must be used for sequential access in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
player = {
    'toto': { point: 15},
    'titi': { point: 8},
    'tete': { point: 5},
    'tata': { point: 10},
    'tutu': { point: 15 }
}

var playerArr = [];
for(var key in player) { 
   player[key].name = key;
   playerArr.push(player[key]);
}

playerArr.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a.point == b.point) return 0;
    if (a.point > b.point) return -1;
    return 1;
})

var best = [];
for(var i = 0; i < playerArr.length; i++) {
    var point = playerArr[i].point;
    if (best.length == 0 || best[best.length - 1].point != point)
        best.push({ point: point, text: playerArr[i].name });        
    else 
        best[best.length - 1].text += ", " + playerArr[i].name;
}

// output
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log("best[" + (i + 1) + "].player = " + best[i].text + ";")
    console.log("best[" + (i + 1) + "].point = " + best[i].point + ";")    
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: You want the exact output you described?

Comment: I'd expect similar output as the OP described. (Which isn't me)

Comment: Yes, I would especially like asking equalities as possible for the first player: I need to know that this is TOTO and TUTU with 15 points.

Comment: Updated to provide you the exact output

Comment: For the last `for` loop, I'd suggest using: `i < output.length && i < 3`, as the OP only wanted the top 3. other than that, nice work! +1

Comment: ... And then the OP changes his desired output completely -.-

Comment: Okay, last update to show new ouput. No more edits please!

Answer (score 1):

Solution can be a little simplier:

```
var player = {
    'toto': { point: 15},
    'titi': { point: 8},
    'tete': { point: 5},
    'tata': { point: 10},
    'tutu': { point: 15 }
},
best = [];

for (var el in player) {
    best.push({player: el, point: player[el].point})
}

best.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.point - a.point;
})
.forEach(function(el, i, arr) {
    if (arr[i+1] && el.point == arr[i+1].point) {
        el.player += ', ' + arr.splice(i+1, 1)[0].player;
    }
});
```

Now `best` contains

```
[
    {"player":"toto, tutu","point":15},
    {"player":"tata","point":10},
    {"player":"titi","point":8},
    {"player":"tete","point":5}
]
```

Comment: What about a three way tie? :)

Comment: What does it mean? Probably I didn't understand something?

Comment: Forget it, I wasn't looking right ... the use of `splice` is a bit odd, though :)

Comment: Very concise, nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

The solution consists of a few steps.

```
var player = {
  toto: { point: 15 },
  titi: { point: 8 },
  tete: { point: 5 },
  tata: { point: 10 },
  tutu: { point: 15 }
};
```

The first step is to create an array out of your `player` object's properties and then sort the array based on the points in reverse order:

```
var scores = Object.keys(player).map(function(key) {
  return {
    name: key,
    points: player[key].point
  };
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.points != b.points) {
    return b.points - a.points;
  }
  return 0;
});
```

Then, iterate and format it:

```
var i = 0,
j = 1,
current;

function getName(item)
{
  return item.name;
}

// only print top 3 (variable j)
while (i < scores.length && j <= 3) {
  current = i++;

  // grab more names based on similar score    
  while (i < scores.length && scores[i].points == scores[current].points) {
    ++i;
  }

  console.log(
    '%d - %d - %s', 
    j, 
    scores[current].points, 
    scores.slice(current, i).map(getName).join(' ')
  );

  ++j;
}
```